# Можно ли перепрошить блютуз адаптер v5.0 под определенный геймпад?

Tags: android, windows, драйвер, bluetooth, wireless

У меня геймпад PXN 9613 и свисток (беспроводной адаптер) вышли из строя по неизвестной причине.

Я знаю как минимум 4 режима подключения геймпада беспроводным путем: `direct input`, `x-input`, `Bluetooth to Android`, `keyboard mode` *(есть ещё один но не известно что это вообще, он перебирает лампочки по одной и его не видно по блютуз)*.

Первые два режима рассчитаны на подключение через родной свисток (dongle), хотя режим `х-input` и к андроид подключается.

Из этих режимов нормально по блютуз к ноуту подключается только режим клавиатуры от которого толку нет, в первых 3 режимах ноут видит джойстик по блютуз и даже пытается подключится, но потом пишет `ошибка драйвера` напротив якобы подключенного геймпада, а геймпад так и не подаёт признаков того, что он подключился хоть и неправильно (пробовал дрова менять - гиблое дело, думаю они тут вообще не при чем, перепробовал кучу вариантов).

Я так понимаю подключение его к ПК по блютузу не рассчитано, только через свисток и шнур. У меня есть блютуз v5.0 адаптер, рабочий, но не нужный мне.

Может есть какой то способ перепрошить его именно под геймпад? Или может можно как то сам геймпад перепрошить, чтобы он в режиме подключения под андроид и с ПК работал нормально? Просто у меня есть другой геймпад который в режиме под андроид с ПК тоже правильно по блютузу работает.